# Is it a bad practice to use multithreading inside of Flume Source implementation?

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng

So the question is what if I'll use some multithreaded logic inside of the Flume Source implementation? Won't it be a bad design?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more which is the purpose of such multithreading logic? I mean, if using HTTPSource, I think some king of multithreading is already implemented since a Jetty server is used to serve multiple concurrent data sendings. In that case, I think it is not necessary nothing else.

Comment: I mean that I want to provide some data transformation logic (i.e. xml records parsing and converting them to another format) into the Flume source. And I want it be multithreaded.

Comment: In order to do that you will need to create a custom sink type... or use HTTPSource by implementing a custom handler; the handler is the code run each time a piece of data is sent through a HTTP request; each request is serverd in an independent thread; and all the logic regarding synchronization writes is already done. Otherwise (if implementing your own source) you will have to be very careful when concurrently writing to the channels configured for the source.